# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to Instantiate a new Enemy from the enemy class and assign it to a variable of type Enemy. But I keep getting this error -> **InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)**.

It points to this line -->

*Enemy enemyTemp = Instantiate(enemyPre, new Vector3(-0.689f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);* as the problem.

Most of it can be completely ignored, but I am declaring the var with this --> *public Enemy enemyPre;*

I put in a prefab of the Enemy inside this var inside the Unity editor itself. I'm using this method so I can reference the specific enemy later. I've tried many different solutions, but nothing seems to work. I find it odd because I did almost the exact same thing with the CameraFollow class and that works just fine. Does anyone  have a solution?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static LevelManager instance;

    public GameObject playerPre;
    public CameraFollow cameraPre;
    public ParticleSystem explodePlayerPre;
    public ParticleSystem explodeEnemyPre;
    public GameObject respawnPre;
    public Enemy enemyPre;
    public KillPoint killPre;
    public GameObject basePre;


    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 playerStartPos, respawnStartPos, cameraStartPos, killPointStartPos;


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level", 1) == 1)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level", 1);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += nextLevel;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= nextLevel;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level", 1));
    }

    public void LevelSelect()
    {
        
    }

    private void nextLevel(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if (scene.name == "MainMenu")
        {




        }

        if (scene.name == "Level1")
        {
            playerStartPos = new Vector3(-1.353f, 0.45f, 0f);
            Instantiate(playerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(basePre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            Instantiate(respawnPre, respawnStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            cameraStartPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f);
            CameraFollow camClone = Instantiate(cameraPre, cameraStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            camClone.minX = -2.24f;
            camClone.maxX = 18.4f;
            camClone.minY = -2.94f;
            camClone.maxY = 1.18f;

            Instantiate(explodePlayerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(explodeEnemyPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

        }
        if (scene.name == "Level2")
        {
            playerStartPos = new Vector3(-3.271f, 1.372f, 0f);
            Instantiate(playerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(basePre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            Instantiate(respawnPre, respawnStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            cameraStartPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f);
            CameraFollow camClone = Instantiate(cameraPre, cameraStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            camClone.minX = -2.24f;
            camClone.maxX = 18.4f;
            camClone.minY = -2.94f;
            camClone.maxY = 3.26f;

            Instantiate(explodePlayerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(explodeEnemyPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        if (scene.name == "Level3")
        {
            playerStartPos = new Vector3(-3.492f, -0.632f, 0f);
            Instantiate(playerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(basePre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            Instantiate(respawnPre, respawnStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            cameraStartPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f);
            CameraFollow camClone = Instantiate(cameraPre, cameraStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            camClone.minX = -2.24f;
            camClone.maxX = 24.17f;
            camClone.minY = -2.94f;
            camClone.maxY = 4.54f;

            Instantiate(explodePlayerPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(explodeEnemyPre, playerStartPos, Quaternion.identity);

            Enemy enemyTemp = Instantiate(enemyPre, new Vector3(-0.689f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            KillPoint killPointTemp = Instantiate(killPre, new Vector3(-0.689f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            killPointTemp.Enemy = enemyTemp;
            enemyTemp = Instantiate(enemyPre, new Vector3(-1.77f, 2.619f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            killPointTemp = Instantiate(killPre, new Vector3(-1.77f, 2.619f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            killPointTemp.Enemy = enemyTemp;

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making sure the var was storing the Class and not the Game object itself inside the Unity editor.

Comment: Correct. You told it to take the enemy component not the game object