# InvalidCastException meaning and how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that creates a projectile, and when I press space to create it, it comes up with this error:

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
(wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <4a31731933e0419ca5a995305014ad37>:0)
ProjectileMovement.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Robert Scenes/Robert Assets/MainAsset/Scripts/ProjectileMovement.cs:33)
```

Can anyone help? Here is my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities;

public class ProjectileMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public double timer = 5;
    public SpacePlayerMovement spaceObject;

    


    private void Start()
    {
        spaceObject = gameObject.AddComponent<SpacePlayerMovement>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        timer = timer - 0.01;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (timer <= 0)
            {
                timer = 0.5;
                var position = spaceObject.player.position;
                Instantiate(bullet, new Vector3(position.x, position.y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                


            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `bullet` is `null` when `Instantiate` is called?

Comment: bullet is created, everything works, I just get this error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate / related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167561/invalidcastexception-specified-cast-is-not-valid-wrapper-castclass-system-ob

Comment: What do the "Instantiate()" method and "Vector3()" constructor  look like?

Comment: Could you post your code of `SpacePlayerMovement`? what exactly is `spaceObject.player.position` and how is `spaceObject.player` even assigned?